# Android: call custom methods in a ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a custom ContentProvider I use to store fixes obtained from the GPS into a SQLite database.  This class overrides ContentProvider methods (delete, insert, query...), but notice I have also included a method to query the last fix.

```
public class FixesContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    @Override
    public int delete(...) { ... }
    ...
    @Override
    public Cursor query(...) { ... }

    public Cursor getLastFix(Uri uri) { ... }
}
```

It is pretty easy to query data from other services or activities by calling `getContentResolver()`.

```
ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
Cursor fixes = cR.query(CONTENT_URI, ...);
```

But I am not able to call my custom method (`FixesContentProvider#getLastFix`).  **How could I call custom methods defined in a ContentProvider?**

Maybe I don't understand how ContentProviders/ContentResolvers work in this case, but official [Android documentation provided by Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) is not very clear in this sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> > But I am not able to call my custom method (`FixesContentProvider#getLastFix`).

That's completely true. In this very case though, you can take advantage of one fact: both `query` and `getLastFix` methods return a `Cursor` object. So, what I do would be adding some value to the URI that you pass to `query` and, then decide what you want to actually do: `query` or `getLastFix`. For instance:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri,...) { 
    if ( uri says it has to return the last fix )
        return getLastFix(uri);
    // otherwise, do normal operations...
    return cursor;
}
```

In fact, the `query` method is suppose to return a result, given a `Uri`. So, if you need to retrieve the last fix, you have to specify in the URI that you want the last fix.

Comment: That is what I did.  I've used UriMatcher.addUri to match "content://xxx/fixes" and "content://xxx/fixes/last" to two different codes, acting accordingly (as you propose) in a switch (myUriMatcher.match(uri)) { case CODE_1: xxx; case CODE_2: yyy; }.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

As of API level 11 there is a method [ContentResolver.call(Uri, String, String, Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#call%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) which provides extra flexibility.