# Custom methods in a ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325601/android-call-custom-methods-in-a-contentprovider) if my custom method in a Content Provider doesn't return a cursor but, for example, a boolean value, how can I call the method? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Return a [`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) that contains a 1x1 matrix of bool.