# Java/Android: how do I access the ContentProvider that is declared in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android

AndroidManifest.xml:
`<provider android:authorities="com.mygame.expansion" android:exported="false" android:multiprocess="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.xapkreader.XAPKProvider" />`

I have an `APEZProvider` class, which comes from the Android SDK /extras folder. It extends `ContentProvider`.

I also have a `XAPKProvider` class, which extends `APEZProvider`:

```
public class XAPKProvider extends APEZProvider {
 @Override public String getAuthority () {return "com.mygame.expansion";}

 public int mainFileVersion  = 0;
 public int patchFileVersion = 0;

 @Override public boolean initIfNecessary () {
  if (mInit) return true;
  Context ctx = getContext ();
  try {
   mAPKExtensionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile (ctx, mainFileVersion, patchFileVersion);
   mInit = true;
   return true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace ();
  }
  return false;
 }
}
```

How can I access the `ContentProvider` object created in the AndroidManifest.xml file, so that I can modify the `mainFileVersion` and `patchFileVersion` variables?

Comment: how can you  access?  what do you mean?

Comment: I want to be able to modify those variables from another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325601/android-call-custom-methods-in-a-contentprovider/15111866#15111866) that got me to the answer. I needed to override "call". For example:

```
ContentResolver cr = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
String expansionAuthority = bundle.getString("expansion_authority", "");
cr.call (Uri.parse("content://" + expansionAuthority), "set_expansion_file_versions", null, bundle);
```

Then:..

```
@Override public Bundle call (String method, String arg, Bundle bundle) {
 if (method.equals("set_expansion_file_versions")) {
  mainFileVersion  = bundle.getInt("main_version" , 1);
  patchFileVersion = bundle.getInt("patch_version", 1);
  expansionAuthority = bundle.getString("expansion_authority", "com.sample.expansion");
  xmlDataReceived = true;
  return null;
 }
 return null;
}
```